# Show dialog when the first time click "open" app on CH Play

Tags: flutter, kotlin

When I have downloaded the application completely from play store and I click on "Open" button the application, I want to show a dialog ( a dialog to confirm get permission in app). After I've confirmed, I want to move directly to the permission detail screen of my application.

My base project is Kotlin. Before MyHomePage in flutter is called, my application need to get permission in kotlin code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `shared_preferences` for your case.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `CH Play`?

Comment: So you need `shared_preferences`. Make a `bool` variable, set it to `false` initially, now check if the variable is false, show the dialog. Once you show the dialog, set the variable to `true` and save the variable in `SharedPreferences`. Next time the dialog won't be shown because its value is `true` now.

Comment: When I don't allow permission, app will not play. This permission is a prerequisite to run application

Comment: When my app haven't run, I think not use shared_preference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short implementation that you can run. Put it simple I'm using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` to call the `_showDialog()` method right when the app started. The `SharedPreferences` is used to remember that the app already show the dialog on the first time, so it won't show again.

Full example code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final isDisplayed = 'isDisplayed';

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      // You can check if the app has permission here as well, instead of
      // checking if the dialog is displayed or not
      if ((await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getBool(isDisplayed))
        _showDialog();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("First Screen"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showDialog() async {
    await (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).setBool(isDisplayed, true);
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Go to Permission Page'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop(); // Dismiss alert dialog
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PermissionScreen()));
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class PermissionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PermissionScreenState createState() => _PermissionScreenState();
}

class _PermissionScreenState extends State<PermissionScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Permission Screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Permission Screen"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Chung You should update the question with this information, so anyone that has the answer can get to it directly